# How to remove required field validation in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

This is driving me crazy!!

I have a very simple page with checkbox and textfield (start_date__c) if the checkbox is checked then the textfield is required so far so good no problem, the start_date__c is required field.

Screen shot 1 Without check:

[image]

Screen shot 2 Checked:

[image]

But when I submit the page without is Present checked then i'm getting this error:

> Start Date required field is missing

I do not have validation rule that specific field but my question is why is it complaining when the `required field is = false` in the visualforce page

```
  <apex:inputField value="{!employee__c.Start_Date__c}" required="false"/>
```

Comment: Are you able to save blank value on standard layout?

Comment: Nick, it is entirely possible this field is marked as "Required" at the object level... Have you checked there?

Comment: @SebastianKessel: I did mentioned in my post but maybe not highlighted the field is "required" in the object level, so if that case then what do i need to ignore that required in visualforce page?

Comment: If the field is required at the object level you're out of luck. Salesforce will not let you save a record with that field blank under any circumstance.

Comment: I have tried to use `immedidate=true` on the Save button but did not help me either.

Comment: If the field is required AT THE OBJECT LEVEL (sorry for caps, that should be bold). `immediate` won't help you either.

Comment: @SebastianKessel: please post this as answer if this is the case then I really have to think my approach, I didn't know about this.

Comment: @Nick, did you solve this question? Which direction did you go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nick,

The main problem (per your comments) is that the field is required *at the object level*. When you make a field required like that, you cannot save a blank value in there in any way (API, code, standard layout).

As Adrian mentioned, you can choose several workarounds.

1) You can make a smart Validation Rule

This will allow you to bypass the requirement in certain cases

2) You can make it required at a Page Layout level

This will let you save blank values via VF or API, but maintain the requirement of the field for people using the standard Page Layout.

3) You can write a trigger

Please don't do it, either of the two cases above should be enough in a simple case like this. :D

Comment: Adrian's answer will only work as I describe in #1 above. But for that you will have to remove the requirement at the object level first

Comment: Just fyi from the comments above, you can make comment text **bold** by wrapping it in double asterisks (e.g. `**bold**`).

Comment: In the comments, too? I did not know that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a `Validation Rule` and modify the field so it is *not* `required` at the database level. It is the only way you can save a record without a value in that field, unless you want to give it a default value under those circumstances, but it does not sound like what you want. Your `Validation Rule` would then be simply:

```
AND(NOT(Is_Present__c), ISBLANK(Start_Date__c))
```

Comment: Do I have remove required requirement at the object level first in order to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I tried to make it clear in my first sentence. You have to remove that attribute or your only option is to fill the field in.

Comment: 1+Thanks Adrian I must have overlooked